# How do I load dynamic template for a vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try load dynamic template in vue component,
But I get errors,

This my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>details</h1>
    <div id="app-3">
      <span>Now you see me{{seen}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Component, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

export default {
mounted(){
    var app3 = new Vue({
      el: "#app-3",
      data: {
        seen: '!!!'
      }
    });
}};
</script>
```

I get two errors:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "seen" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render.
>
> Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the
>   template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
>   into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

Comment: Are you looking for `mounted()`?

Comment: you have some other issue. you should put everything in your `export default`. doing it like this is not the right way to do it

Comment: Thanks, I change two problems,
But now I get error is data is not defined on the instance,

Comment: data() { 
    return {
         seen: '!!!'
    }
}